# Hide elements on certain pages

Tags: reactjs

How can I hide Topbar on Login and Register pages? I'm trying to show the Topbar on all pages but hide it on Login and Register pages

**The Code**

```
return (
    <Router>
  
      <TopBar/>

      <Routes>

        <Route path="/register" element={user ? <Home /> : <Register />} >
        </Route>

        <Route path="/login" element={user ? <Home /> : <Login />}>
        </Route>

        <Route path="/settings" element={user ? <Settings /> : <Register />}>
        </Route>

      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cloud try something like this

```
{window.location.pathname != "/Login" &&
        window.location.pathname != "/Register" && <Topbar />}
```

window.location.pathname **//returns the current url minus the domain name**

Or since your using user  object to detect whether the current user is login or not why not use it in your logic as well .

```
 {user && <Topbar />}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can return `null` inside the components you want to hide when the path matches `/login` or `/register` using [`useLocation()`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-location) hook:

```
const TopBar = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  if (pathname === "/login" || pathname === "/register") return null;

  return (
    // ...
  );
}
```

---

#### Edit:

When you are on your `<Home>` component, the `<TopBar>` will not appear because you conditionally render it on the excluded routes. You can solve this problem by removing the conditions in your routes and moving them in your components instead. It means that each route will always renders the same component (or redirect to another route).

First, you can remove the conditions in your three routes and add a `/home` route:

```
<Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
```

And then on the components that need a redirection, you can use React Router's [`<Navigate>`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/navigate):

```
const Login = () => {
  // If you can't access `user` here you can pass it as a prop
  if (user) return <Navigate to="/home" />

  return (
    // ...
  );
}
```

Since all your routes depend on `user`, if you don't want to put a `<Navigate>` on every components you can create a helper component to deal with it:

```
const WithRedirect = ({ to, children }) => (
  if (user) return <Navigate to={to} />
  return children;
};
```

And then:

```
<Route
  path="/login"
  element={
    <WithRedirect to="/home"> 
      <Login />
    </WithRedirect>
  }
/>
```

Comment: It worked, but when I'm on home page the topbar disappear also!! I want it to disappear on login and register pages only !

Comment: @sultan.h I just made a mistake while writing the code. You can put any pathname you want to exclude in the if condition. I edited my answer.

Comment: its the same, I think its because of this code >> element={user ? <Home /> : <Login />

Comment: @sultan.h Yes, I see. I edited my answer again.

Comment: thank you for answering, you are the best, but the answer didn't work with me ! thank you again